# ExtJS 4 Localization on real time

Tags: javascript, extjs, localization, extjs4

I would like to know if someone can guide me on the way on how to manage localization in extjs 4. I want to know if there is way to handle the language changing in real time, without the need of refresh the page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All ExtJS supports is that you can create locale specific JS files and based on certain logic in your application (e.g. the language code from your user profile) you will have to, dynamically, add a script tag to the document head so that the view can be localized for that user.

You may refer to the existing locale specific files in locale folder of your ExtJS folder.

Answer (score 0):

See the [dynamic localization example in the ExtJS docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/locale/multi-lang.html).